# ¿Como puedo detectar un evento (popup) solo dentro polígono en Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

[Consulte también la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790344/determine-if-a-point-reside-inside-a-leaflet-polygon)

Tengo un mapa hay varias geometrías (puntos, líneas, polígonos), agregadas como geoJson. Cuando hace clic DENTRO de un polígono, se activa el evento (popup) de clic. Y hace clic fuera de un polígono, no se activa el evento (Popup)

```
//Clic coordenada y marcar el punto

    var popup = L.popup();
    map.on('click',function(e){
    lat = e.latlng.lat;
    lon = e.latlng.lng;
    popup
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)       
    .setContent("Has hecho click en la coordenada:<br> " +  lat + "," +  lon)        
    .openOn(map);
    document.getElementById('coordenada').value = lat + " , "+lon;
    if (marker != undefined) {
          map.removeLayer(marker);
    };
     marker = L.marker([lat,lon],{icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);  
});
```

Rellenar el poligono

```
       L.geoJson([campus], {

        style: function (feature) {
            return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
        },
        
    }).addTo(map);
```

Donde le pongo la funcion isMarkerInsidePolygon o donde esta llamando la función

```
function isMarkerInsidePolygon(marker, campus) {
        var inside = false;
        var x = marker.getLatLng().lat, y = marker.getLatLng().lng;
        for (var ii=0;ii<campus.getLatLngs().length;ii++){
            var polyPoints = campus.getLatLngs()[ii];
            for (var i = 0, j = polyPoints.length - 1; i < polyPoints.length; j = i++) {
                var xi = polyPoints[i].lat, yi = polyPoints[i].lng;
                var xj = polyPoints[j].lat, yj = polyPoints[j].lng;

                var intersect = ((yi > y) != (yj > y))
                    && (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);
                if (intersect) inside = !inside;
            }
        }

        return inside;
    };
```

Comment: Bienvenido, te recomiendo hacer el [tour]. No termino de entender. ¿Tu problema es que el popup se muestra en otro lugar que NO son las coordenadas que has introducido? Podrias explicar un poco mejor?

Comment: Ya resolví mi problema. Espero que me entiende

Comment: Y ¿cual fué el problema? y ¿Cual es la solucion?

Comment: Asi es, si pudieras contestar tu propia pregunta seria genial. Leaflet es una libreria muy buena y hay muy pocas preguntas en el sitio. Creo que seria una muy buena contribucion.

Comment: Aun sigo sin entender

Comment: En lugar de agregar en tu pregunta el enlace que te dio la solución, agrega su contenido (traducido) como respuesta, y luego [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tal respuesta, ya que te ha sido útil.